# Android FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime() is slow

Tags: java, android, video, frames

I'm working on an app which will ultimately cut up a video into frames at say 200 millisecond intervals.

The app works, you select a video and the app will cut it up into Bitmaps which are stored on the device. The problem is, FFmpegMediaMetaRetriever.getFrameAtTime() is incredibly slow. I mean, it takes longer to process the video than the video length itself, I'm seeing around 1.1 second average per frame.

I've tracked the delay down to the call for getFrameAtTime. Does anyone else out there know of a better way of achieving obtaining frames from a video at specific times?

Code:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever.setDataSource(getPath(EditVideo.this, mMediaUri));
            String time = retriever.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);

            // FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever doesn't have the ability to get Width and Height of video, needed to scale down to 1024.
            MediaMetadataRetriever retriever1 = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            retriever1.setDataSource(getPath(EditVideo.this, mMediaUri));
            int width = Integer.parseInt(retriever1.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH));
            int height = Integer.parseInt(retriever1.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT));
            retriever1.release();

            int videoDuration = Integer.parseInt(time);

            int newWidth = 1024;
            int newHeight = Math.round(height * (1024f / width));

            Bitmap bitmap;
            for(int i=0;i<videoDuration;i+=mFrameEvery){

                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(i*1000, FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                Log.d(TAG,"Took: " + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000f));

                final Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);

                try {
                    File frameFile = getOutputMediaFile("IMAGEFILE",rev.size());
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(frameFile);
                    scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fos);
                    fos.close();

                    rev.add(frameFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
                            totalFrames.setText("Total Frames: " + rev.size());
                        }
                    });
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    seekBar.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Log:

```
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.448
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.147
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.162
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.322
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.301
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.453
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.108
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.165
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.292
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.358
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.369
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.06
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.13
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.183
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.177
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.231
D/EditVideo: Took: 0.924
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.007
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.092
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.104
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.211
D/EditVideo: Took: 0.923
D/EditVideo: Took: 0.994
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.119
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.138
D/EditVideo: Took: 1.193
```

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @AntonShkurenko unfortunately not no. I tried to 'speed it up' by introducing multithreading, but it appears FFMpeg isn't threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I use the MediaMetadataRetriver, the process time is about 0.7 second in average. I also find some methods to decrease the time to get the frame.